# Draw lines of various lengths after text all to a specific point in the block

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and have looked for answers to this question, but whilst I have found similar ones nothing matches my circumstances.

I want to draw lines of various lengths after some text to a specific point in a block

This works with the number after the indent right class being the %age of padding=right applied to extend the border bottom:

```
<span class="kimmeridgedescription1841">County of<span class="italic"><span class="kimmeridgenameinsert">D</span><span class="indentright46">orset</span></span></span>
<span class="kimmeridgedescription1841">Hundred, Wapentake, Soke or Liberty of<span class="italic"><span class="kimmeridgenameinsert">H</span><span class="indentright01">asilor</span></span></span>
```

There are ten of these lines however each with different lengths, so whilst works it reflects my lack of detailed knowledge.

The web page is http://www.c5d.co.uk/descriptionkimmeridge1841.php and if you were to look at that, I guess it becomes obvious what I need. Incidentally the word Purbeck is intended to be beyond the extent of the line

Thank you

```
.kimmeridgedescription1841 span.borough { font-style:normal;line-height:0; display:block; text-indent:25px;text-align:left;}
.kimmeridgedescription1841 {margin:auto; font-style:normal;line-height:3;display:block;}
.kimmeridgedescription1841a {margin:auto; font-style:normal;line-height:5;display:block;}
.kimmeridgedescription1841div {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:450px;}
.kimmeridge1841bracket {
    float: right;
    font-size: x-large;
    margin-right: 25%;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-top: -5px; }

.kimmeridgedescription1841hr {
    width: 33%;
    border-bottom: black;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-right: 50%;
}
.kimmeridgenameinsert {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
    padding-left:2%
}
.indentright01 {
   border-bottom:1px solid black; 
}
.indentright2 {
  padding-right:2%; 
  border-bottom:1px solid black; 
}
```

Comment: I have looked at your webpage in some different browsers. but I am not sure which one I'm supposed to be using.

Comment: What do you mean? What I want to know is there a way to extend the lines to their current lengths without using eight different CSS classes? This is used all the time with just the length of the padding changed .indentright2 {
  padding-right:2%; 
  border-bottom:1px solid black; 
}

Comment: Yeah, but in many browsers the problem of the lines is overshadowed by the problem of the menu items all being visible. Here, a screenshot.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6pHy.jpg

Comment: I had only tried it in Chrome IE and Firefox. which ones does it not work in? The drop down menu has been there for many years and I have not touched that. Maybe it hasn't worked for many years but no one has said!

Comment: Sorry, I said "many browsers", but it seems to be contained to Firefox and Chrome under Linux (which were the first two I tried), and then only to some versions of those. I'll have to do some more testing!